# Is it possible to name a QThread?

Tags: rename, qt, multithreading

I have a Linux Qt application that creates some `QThreads`.

I know that when you create a thread it inherits the parent name and I can see it when I use `htop` or `ps ax -L`.

Is it possible to name those QThreads and see their names via a bash command like `ps ax -L` or ‍`htop`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes just give the name to the QThread object before starting it:

```
QThread* thr = new QThread(this);

thr->setObjectName("worker thread");
```

In [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#managing-threads):

> To choose the name that your thread will be given (as identified by
> the command `ps -L` on Linux, for example), you can call [`setObjectName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#setObjectName)
> before starting the thread. If you don't call [`setObjectName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#setObjectName), the
> name given to your thread will be the class name of the runtime type
> of your thread object (for example, `"RenderThread"` in the case of the
> [Mandelbrot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html) example, as that is the name of the `QThread` subclass). Note
> that this is currently not available with release builds on Windows.

Comment: thank you for answering... I already tryed that way without success, `ps ax -L` doesn't show the name I gave to it but the "Target" name... Any explanation?

Comment: yes, I did this: `t1 = new QThread(); t1->setObjectName("worker"); t1->start();`

Comment: have you ever tryed that solution?

Comment: How to kill this thread, by selecting it with the name given?